# How to add link to new document of a particular content type

Tags: content-type, document

I have a document library with an associated content type. I've added a file in the template section of the content Type. 
In the document library area, in the ribbon I can create a new document based on the content type.

I need to create a shortcut on another site (same site collection) that allows the user to create this document based on the CT. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Your another site is on same site collection?

Comment: Yes, can be same site collection, but as an option can it work across differing site collections?

Comment: You can create the content type at site collection level and add that content type to other library in another site.

Comment: I want to be able to create a shortcut for the user rather than the user having to go to the ribbon and selecting new document.